# Integrating Google Cloud Speech API with Android

Tags: java, android, credentials, service-accounts, google-cloud-speech

I'm attempting to grab a credential using a service account's private .json key, and it always throws GeneralSecurityException here.

I'm doing this on android, and after reading forums it seems there have been issues with fromStream and other dependencies in your project (https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/issues/979) - does anybody have any advice?

```
InputStream credentialsJSON = context.getAssets().open("mykey.json");
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(credentialsJSON, httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY);
```

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/Speech/app/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/android/speech/AccessTokenLoader.java#L77  review the android sample and swap in your downloaded credentials file.. but dont use that in PROD due to security (as per docs

Comment: Wouldn't dream of using it in production hahaha

Thanks man, looking through it now.

Comment: @RobertRowntree I'm getting an exception when I call final AccessToken token = credential.refreshAccessToken();

Comment: I'm printing my key out and can verify it is correct, and I've tested it through terminal with a curl request if that helps. EDIT: I've found some things I was doing wrong, let me investigate first.

Comment: credential.json which you download , is not a key . Its a json object with aobut 8 elements... if you have that ,  i think the refresh will be OK

Comment: Solved it - thanks for pointing me to the sample, I've been searching for days and it never once came up!

Comment: Excuse my noob question: In the case of production apps, what is the safe alternative to putting the credentials file inside the Raw folder?